# Product of matrices and system of equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have tried everything in my power but I still cant figure how to do this :/

$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$$

How can I show that if $A$ is a $2\times3$ matrix, then the system: $$Ax=\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}$$ has infinite solutions?

I'm really sure that this is pretty elementary but I can manage to see how to do this.

EDIT: In class we havent studied inverses yet!

Thanks so much!

Comment: You're asking two very different questions here. The answer to the first is NO. To answer the second one: have you studied the Gauss elimination method yet?

Comment: nope, nothing with determinants nor inverses

Comment: Assuming that $A$ in your second question is the same as the $A$ in your first question, can you first prove that $Ax = [1;3]$ has _at least one_ solution? [This is not always the case, for example if $A$ is the all-zero matrix then $Ax=[1;3]$ has no solutions, but it is true if the $A$ matrix of your first and second questions are the same]

Comment: @Michael I know it has at least one solution cause if A is 2x3 then $B=[b_{1} b_{2}]$. Now, since $AB=[Ab_{1} Ab_{2}]$, this means that $Ab_{1}=[1 3]^{t}$, so x is at least $b_{1}$

Comment: Okay so that is the first step.  Now, if you know $Ax=c$ has a _particular_ solution $p$, do you know how to construct _all solutions_?  In other words, $Ax=c$ is true if and only if $x$ is [...related to $p$ somehow...]

Comment: Ohh, then x is a linear combination of something by b_{1}?

Comment: I used the term _particular solution_ $p$  since I thought you may have seen a theorem about that. Well another way to think of it is this: If you found a nonzero vector $v$ such that $Av=0$, could you use that to find a second solution to $Ax=c$? Could you use that to find infinitely many solutions?